# Using a Salt State to Query a Postgres Table and Use Return Values

Tags: postgresql, salt-stack

As the title suggests is it possible to say... install a list of packages that are stored in a Postgres database table.
Example:

```
    testing=# select * from package;
 name
-------
 rsync
 lftp
 curl
(3 rows)
```

Then use these values in a state to install the appropriate packages.. something like:

```
install_network_packages:
 pkg.installed:
   pkgs:
    - 'select * from package'
```

I currently have this state that returns the values of the table, but do not know where to go from there:

```
testing:
  module.run:
    - name: postgres.psql_query
    - query: 'select * from public.package'
    - maintenance_db: testing
```

Output:

### minion1:

```
      ID: testing
Function: module.run
    Name: postgres.psql_query
  Result: True
 Comment: Module function postgres.psql_query executed
 Started: 15:25:23.161788
Duration: 79.784 ms
 Changes:
          ----------
          ret:
              |_
                ----------
                name:
                    rsync
              |_
                ----------
                name:
                    lftp
              |_
                ----------
                name:
                    curl
```

### Summary for minion1

Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)

### Failed:    0

Total states run:     1
Total run time:  79.784 ms

Answer (score 1):

Good question! The salt component that typically stores this sort of data (what packages should be installed what role a server has, etc.) is called the ["pillar"](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/).

Typically, pillar data is stored internally in the salt master, but salt also has a (rather poorly documented) feature called ["external pillars"](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/external_pillars.html) that allows you to query and use other data sources (postgres, an arbitrary command line call, etc.) the same way you use builtin pillars. It seems that in the development version of salt (Nitrogen) there's a builtin [postgres external pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.postgres.html). I imagine you could use it on the release version by just copy pasting [the code](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/pillar/postgres.py) into your external modules directory (I've done this successfully in the past with unreleased salt features).

Best of luck!

Comment: Okay thanks for the links! I've just been experimenting around and hoping to find a solution. Cheers!